# Find those who have NOT written a letter

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have three tables: tblAreas, which describes various areas of the UK; tblNewsletters, which lists quarterly dates when we publish newsletters; tblIssues, which is a many-to-many table linking the previous two. tbl Issues describes each newsletter produced by each area in each quarter (one newsletter per area per quarter). I want to find those areas which have not produced a newsletter in a given quarter. To make a start, I did not attempt to restrict output to a particular quarter, but couldn't even get that to work. Here is my code:

```
SELECT tblArea.ID, tblArea.AreaName
    FROM tblIssues
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT NewsletterLookup
             FROM tblIssues
             WHERE tblIssues.AreaLookup = tblArea.ID);
```

Comment: Well for starters you are referencing a `tlbArea` table (or alias) in your `SELECT` and subquery that's not in your `FROM` clause. Other than that I see no obvious syntax issues.  Did you mean `FROM tblArea` instead?

Comment: The area doesn't describe newsletters. using your comment I tried the following but it only yielded a prompt for a new record. (pressing ENTER only saves my comment - can't indent the following):     SELECT tblArea.ID, tblArea.AreaName
    FROM tblIssues INNER JOIN tblArea ON tblIssues.AreaLookup = tblArea.ID
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT NewsletterLookup
             FROM tblIssues INNER JOIN tblArea ON tblIssues.AreaLookup = tblArea.ID
             WHERE tblIssues.AreaLookup = tblArea.ID);

Comment: Please don't post SQL or code longer than a few words in comments. **Edit** your question and add it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * 
from tblArea a
left join tblIssues i on i.AreaId = a.Id
where i.AreaId is null
```

For a specific quarter, you will have to use a subquery.

```
Select * 
from tblArea a
left join (select AreaId 
           from tblIssues ii
           inner join Newsletters n on n.Id = ii.NewsLetterId
           where n.IssueDate = #12/31/2015#
           ) i on i.AreaId = a.Id
where i.AreaId is null
```

Not tested..sorry

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand 'tblArea a'  'tblIssues i' 'i.AreaId'

Comment: these are `ALIAS`es.You can also write from `tblArea as a`. Google for `sql alias`. I became addicted to those. You create a *synonym* for a table name. Makes your coding more concise and readable (IMO), and it allows you to quickly target another table just by changing the name before the alias.

Comment: Was there a reason you wrote 'AreaId' and not 'Area.Id'?

Comment: Because I don't know (or did not spend enough time on) your field names. If the PK of tblArea is called `id` then it should be `a.id`. I will fix my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first build the cartesian product of all areas and newsletters, 
which is

`SELECT a.ID, n.ID
    FROM tblAreas a, tblNewsletter n`

*(just saw there is no `cross join` in access)* Then you need to cross out all issues, that do actually exist. Normally you would use a syntax like

`MINUS 
  SELECT i.AreaLookup, i.NewsletterID
    from tblIssues i`

But that doesn't exist in MSAccess, so you could use a `NOT IN` workaround for that, which would look something like

`WHERE a.id & "-" & n.ID 
  NOT IN ( SELECT i.AreaLookup & "-" & i.NewsletterID FROM tblIssues i )`

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution using two queries - one based upon the other. What I'd like to do now is find a way of doing it all in one query, perhaps using a subquery.

```
SELECT tblIssues.*, tblIssues.NewsletterLookup
FROM tblIssues
WHERE (((tblIssues.NewsletterLookup)=5));

SELECT tblArea.ID, tblArea.AreaName
FROM tblArea LEFT JOIN Query2 ON tblArea.ID = Query2.[AreaLookup]
WHERE (((tblArea.Dormant)=False) AND ((Query2.tblIssues.NewsletterLookup) Is Null));
```